# What's the best way for a .NET windows forms application to update itself?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, auto-update

I use a home-grown system where the application updates itself from a web service.  However, I seem to remember something in the original .NET sales pitch about auto-updating of components being a built-in feature of .NET.  What are the best practices for having an application update itself and/or the assemblies it uses?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may want to take a look at the Click-Once technology. Some great examples in these references.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/QuickClickOnceArticle.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163973.aspx

Comment: @Jorge Ferreira: +1 ClickOnce is great, unfortunately you run into issues if your app is command line or is more complicated than a single executable. Otherwise, go go ClickOnce.

Comment: I actually can't use ClickOnce because it isn't currently supported by the Compact Framework (the app has to run on that also).  I'm going to post another question excluding ClickOnce as an option.

Comment: Click once is a bit of a hassle in the long run, as if the certificate expires, it offers no was of "bridging" to a new certificate. Your users have to suck it up, uninstall, and reinstall.

Comment: @Gregory: see my SO answer for an answer to this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726275/self-sign-certificate-to-authenticode-certificate/969186#969186

Answer (score 0):

Will [ClickOnce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142dbbz4.aspx) do everything you want?