# Self Sign Certificate To Authenticode Certificate?

Tags: clickonce, code-signing

We deployed a windows application via ClickOnce and a self signer certificate that we created. We are now looking in to getting a Authenticode Certificate from a Certificate Authority like VeriSign.

When we start signing our ClickOnce manifests with the new certificate, will our users have to re-install the application?

Are there any known migration paths for dealing with our scenario?

Thanks

Answer (score 8):

Yes, you can do this without the users having to re-install, but it's tricky. The key is to realise that the application manifests have an Authenticode signature (to identify the publisher) and a strong name signature (to prevent tampering). The trick is to use your old certificate for the strong name signature, and the new certificate for the Authenticode signature.

Neither VS2005/Mage or the sign tool (signtool.exe) from the .NET Framework SDK supports this kind of signing. But the [Windows Server 2003 R2 Platform SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=0BAF2B35-C656-4969-ACE8-E4C0C0716ADB&displaylang=en) contains a newer version of signtool.exe with a new switch "/manifest" and with options to use different keys for signing. With this tool you can sign the ClickOnce manifests with different keys for each of the two signatures.

You can find [more details here](http://blogs.msdn.com/danielma/archive/2007/03/19/clickonce-and-expired-certificates.aspx).